# python select method getting stuck

Tags: python, select

I am trying to make a multiclient https server in python. In order to get the connections in ports 80 and 443, I use select twice. for some reason the program is stuck when I use select for the 2nd time (I checked that by printing something on the lines before and after the select). In the main method I make a `ConnectionHandler` object and use `handle_connections` in a loop. Here are the important parts of `ConnectionHandler` (i use select in `handle_connections`). Also, because I am still writing the rest of the program, I am not really using the https connections for now, so ignore those "bugs".How do I make it work?

```
class ConnectionHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.open_http_sockets = []
        self.open_https_sockets = []
        self.settings = MemoryHandler.get_server_settings()
        self.http_socket = socket.socket()
        self.http_socket.bind((self.settings['http_ip'], int(self.settings['http_port'])))
        self.http_socket.listen(10)
        self.https_socket = socket.socket()
        self.https_socket.bind((self.settings['https_ip'], int(self.settings['https_port'])))
        self.https_socket.listen(10)


    def handle_connections(self):
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([self.http_socket] + self.open_http_sockets, [], [])
        for socket in rlist:
            if socket is self.http_socket:
                # handle the server http socket
                client, address = socket.accept()
                print 'new connection ' + address[0]
                self.open_http_sockets.append(client)
            else:
                # handle all other http sockets
                self.http_communication(socket)
        #the problem is here
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([self.https_socket] + self.open_https_sockets, [], [])
        for socket in rlist:
            if socket is self.https_socket:
                # handle the server https socket
                client, address = socket.accept()
                self.open_https_sockets.append(client)
            else:
                # handle all other https sockets
                self.https_communication(socket)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, `select` is put into a single loop. A `select` blocks the program until an event occurs. So, if the first loop succeeds, then the second will start, but will not attend to the normal `http` connections.

I suggest you do a single select, and include (in the `if`) both `http` and `https` connections.

Something like:

```
for socket in rlist:
    if socket is self.http_socket:
        client, address = socket.accept()
        print 'new connection ' + address[0]
        self.open_http_sockets.append(client)
    elif socket is self.https_socket:
        # handle the server https socket
        client, address = socket.accept()
        self.open_https_sockets.append(client)
    else:
        # handle all other sockets
        self.http_communication(socket)
```